# Is there a way to control boost output_test_stream "record vs. check" behavior without recompile?

Tags: c++, boost, boost.test

I am using Boost.Test class `output_test_stream` to verify that my app provides the expected output. This class provides an easy method to compare the output data vs. known-good recorded data in a file, by invoking the `match_pattern()` method. Here is how I use it:

```
#if defined( CREATE_TEST_PATTERNS )
    bool pattern_test = false;
#else
    bool pattern_test = true;
#endif
boost::test_tools::output_test_stream ostrg("test_output_ref.txt", pattern_test);
my_class_under_test cl(arg1, arg2, ostrg);
...
BOOST_CHECK( ostrg.match_pattern() );
```

The desired output is in the file test_output_ref.txt. The call to `match_pattern()` compares the data in `ostrg` to the data in the file.
If the varaible `pattern_test` is false, the call to `match_pattern()` will instead save the data from `ostrg` to the ref data file `test_output_ref.txt`.

The way I use it is, I first build with the macro `CREATE_TEST_PATTERNS` defined, and run the test program (the tests run as a post build step), to collect the output into a file, visually inspect the output file to make sure the output was correct, and then I re-build the test program with `CREATE_TEST_PATTERNS` *not* defined. In this mode, the test compares the previously recorded expected result to the result generated by the test run.
So far so good.

My question is this: Is there a way to achieve control over the record/check behavior of `match_pattern()` without having to recompile the test program?

Comment: What is wrong with reading a user input and setting `pattern_test` accordingly? Or is your question _how_ to do this?

Comment: The test needs to be able to run "in the background" as part of continuous integration framework. I guess I can extend your question and have the test program read a file to set the value, so thanks for the tip.

Comment: You say that you "visually inspect the output file to make sure the output was correct". What would be your way to check this automatically?

Comment: Responding further to your first question first: I prefer not to have to use files or other input because it creates additional dependencies that make it more difficult to manage. The input file needs to be provided along with the program, put in the right place, etc.

Comment: As to your second question, I visually inspect once, when creating the reference data. Then as regression testing I only read the file and use the boost test automation to compare the file against the latest output. Of course, if I make changes to the part that produces this output, I have to again collect a new known-good sample.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating, but to me this all sounds overly complicated. Maybe I still don't get the problem. Your question is: "Is there a way to achieve control over the record/check behavior of `match_pattern()` without having to recompile the test program?". The answer is: Yes, use _any (runtime) means_ to assign a boolean value to `pattern_test` other than your (compile time) `define`.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to pass a command-line argument to the test or some other way that would work "unattended" and not require additional parts (like files), but could not find any way of doing that. I guess I can also use an environment variable, though I dislike that path because it operates via side effects and is not immediately visible to others.